# FatalErrorException Laravel 5 Socialite Facebook Login

Tags: laravel-5

I’ve just started to use Laravel and I’m trying to implement Socialite in my project in order to log in with Facebook and later to register users through it. I’ve watching the tutorial about Socialite on Laracasts, but I’ve got this error:

> "FatalErrorException in AuthenticateUser.php line 34: Call to a member function driver() on a non-object"

I have no idea why it happens and I’d appreciate some help!

Here is the code I have.

`AuthController` class:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  use App\Http\Requests;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\AuthenticateUser;

  class AuthController extends Controller {

  public function login(AuthenticateUser $authenticateUser, Request $request){
    return $authenticateUser->execute($request->has('code'));
  }// End function
}// End class
```

`AuthenticateUser` class:

```
<?php namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticator;
 use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;
 use App\Data\UserData;

 class AuthenticateUser{
    private $socialite;
    private $auth;
    private $users;

    /* Constructor */
    public function _construct(UserData $users, Socialite $socialite, Authenticator $auth){
    $this->users = $users;
    $this->socialite = $socialite;
    $this->auth = $auth;

}// End constructor

/*  @hasCode : boolean 

*/
public function execute($hasCode){
    if(!$hasCode)
        return $this->getAuthorizationFirst();

    $user = $this->socialite->driver('facebook')->user();
    dd($user);
}

/* Método auxiliar para autorizar el login, si no se tiene el código de autorización */
private function getAuthorizationFirst(){
    return $this->socialite->driver('facebook')->redirect(); //line 34
  }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return 'Welcome back, ' . Auth::user()->username;
    } else {
        return 'Hi guest. ' . link_to('login', 'Login with facebook');
    }
});

Route::get('login','AuthController@login');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor is named incorrectly. It should begin with two underscores:

```
public function __construct(UserData $users, Socialite $socialite, Authenticator $auth);
```

Comment: Don't worry about. Sometimes it just take an extra pair of eyes.